# How to tell OpenSSL about new certificates for an outgoing API call using a Rails ssl_post?

Tags: ruby, openssl, ruby-on-rails-5, ssl-certificate, aws-opsworks

FedEx recently [updated their certificates](https://www.fedex.com/en-us/developer/announcements.html#sept-2020) for their API, which is causing a Rails [ssl_post](https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping/blob/master/lib/active_shipping/carriers/fedex.rb#L740) to their servers in the active_shipping module to throw the error `The SSL connection to the remote server could not be established`.

The application is Rails 5.0 & Ruby 2.3.1, served on AWS EC2 (Amazon Linux) via OpsWorks.

The new certificate files are more or less these:

- gateway.fedex.com.pem (contains one certificate)
- gateway-intermediate.pem (contains two certificates)
- DigiCertGlobalRoot.pem (contains one certificate)

OpenSSL config:

- `openssl version` returns `OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015`.
- `openssl version -d` returns `OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"`

Inside `/etc/pki/tls/` is `cert.pem` and a `certs` directory. I've tried both adding the certificates to `cert.pem` and adding them to the `certs` directory. I've also tried adding them to `/etc/ssl/certs`, and appending them to both `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt` and `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.trust.crt`. I've tried creating an `SSL_CERT_DIR` environment variable and then a `SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variable pointing to each of these locations.

So I have these new certificates; how do I tell OpenSSL about them? Where do I put them? I'm finding lots of documentation and advice about how to set up a certificate to secure the primary domain for web requests, but very little on how to configure a secondary certificate provided by a third-party. I feel like anyone using `active_shipping` and trying to access the FedEx API must be having this same problem, but I have yet to find anyone discussing it.

(As a bonus, FedEx reported they would be renewing their certificates on [October 4, 2020](https://web.archive.org/web/20200924094630/https://www.fedex.com/en-us/developer/announcements.html), then renewed them a week early on 9/26, then went back and edited their announcement page on 9/28 to show the certificates would be renewed on 9/26.)

Answer (score 1):

I finally got to the bottom of this.

[ActiveShipping](https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping) uses [ActiveUtils](https://github.com/Shopify/active_utils) to connect to third-party servers. ActiveUtils uses its own [certfile.pem](https://github.com/Shopify/active_utils/blob/master/lib/certs/cacert.pem), which needs to be updated.

I followed the advice [here](https://github.com/Shopify/active_utils/issues/102), though I also had to add an override the `CA_FILE` for ActiveUtils, so to be explicit:

1. Download the latest bundle from here:
   https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
2. Place the file somewhere in your project. I chose `config/ssl/cacert.pem` as in benjaminwood's example. I had to create the `ssl` directory, as it didn't exist.
3. Create an initializer like the following:

```rb
# config/initializers/00_monkeypatch_updated_ca_cert.rb

module ActiveMerchant
  class Connection
    CA_FILE = Rails.root.join('config', 'ssl', 'cacert.pem').to_s
  end
end

module ActiveUtils
  class Connection
    CA_FILE = Rails.root.join('config', 'ssl', 'cacert.pem').to_s
  end
end
```

...and that got me up and running again.